# How do I level up?

Tags: manyland

I am currently level two, and I've been playing for a few days without levelling up. The official documentation doesn't give much away - what determines when I advance to level 3?

Answer (score 3):

Try exploring all the dialogs, collect things, create things, and importantly, meet others and gain natural upvotes (including upvotes by rank 5ers). You don't need to build, collect or do anything in big numbers though.